# Alfred word to PDF script / workflow

Tags: pdf, workflow, alfred

I'm looking for a workflow for Alfred to convert a word doc to a PDF - I can only find one script that doesnt seem to work (http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/700-convert-word-document-to-pdf-version-16/).

Does anyone have a workflow, script for this or any idea how I can develop the script - I've been searching and cant find anything that seems to work!!

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a relevant sample of the script you tried. Including the link is good, but since links can break, it's also good to summarize them in your question. Also, please be more specific. What doesn't work? Is any file output at all? Is it garbage or just not well-formatted?

Answer (score 0):

To write your own script, you will need to use AppleScript. [This script](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15180576#15180576) ought to work. Put this in a `Run Script` action and give it a `Keyword` and you ought to have a simple workflow to do what you need.